# Android: How to move navigation drawer to the right by a few "dp"

Tags: android

I want to move the button of the navigation drawer located at the top left of the screen, to the right by a few "dp" so that you can see space between the screen and the navigational drawer button.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: hm. You mean the NavigationDrawer?

Comment: yes sir. thats what I mean

Comment: Check this for more help http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to create your own custom view using: `actionBar.setCustomView(View)` & `actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

Or you can try:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

or do the same if you use a drawable instead.

Edit: Actually, this might just effect your icon and not the drawer toggle.

I'm guessing you would have to change this:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```

Specifically, you would need to get the ic_drawer drawable and add in the left padding yourself.